# Compile cat mario

Tags: c++, directx

When I compile the game by using Visual Studio 2010, it shows error LNK1104: cannot open file 'DxLib.lib'. I already follow the directX documentation for C++ to set up the this game compilation project.

Why it shows this error? What kind of stuffs I lacks and make it cannot compile?

Here is the download link.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8v34imehmwvzsvv/cat%20mario.zip

Here are is the compiler output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: cat mario, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 12/5/2013 10:38:24 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\cat mario.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'DxLib.lib'
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.17
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Looks relevant: https://github.com/andrewgbliss/DXLib

Comment: Sidenote: Why is your entire game in main.cpp? O_o

Comment: @Magtheridon96, I don't think it's the OP's. It's a pretty fun game.

Comment: Oh I just noticed "the" before "game". silly me

Answer (score 0):

Seems like build path is not correct, or DxLib.lib is corrupted (not sure about this, though), or you're just missing this library. Try to compile with /LIBPATH:path_to_your_lib_folder.